# IValueConverter not updating the image source

Tags: c#, binding, prism, ivalueconverter

I have this ObservableCollection in my ViewModel:

```
 private ObservableCollection<Component> _standardComponents;
 public ObservableCollection<Component> StandardComponents
        {
            get { return _standardComponents; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _standardComponents, value); }
        }
```

One of its properties

```
public bool ExistInDatabase { get; set; }
```

is changing depending on user action.

Im displaying this property in my ListView using IValueConverter like this:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(BitmapImage))]
    public class BoolToBitmapImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var bitmapImage = ((bool)value == true) ? "Images/Green Ball.png" : "Images/Red Ball.png";
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri($"/Proxos.Core;Component/{bitmapImage}", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And in my View Im using this template as a dynamic resource:

```
 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Image Source="{Binding ExistInDatabase, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBitmapImageConverter}}" Height="17" Width="17"/>
     </DataTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

To display converted ExistInDatabase property in my ListView:

```
<ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.RowSpan="10"  x:Name="_componentListView" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding StandardComponents, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" View="{DynamicResource componentsList}" SelectedIndex="{Binding ComponentSelectedIndex}" >
```

It works fine when I load the UserControll for the first time but when I update the property ExistInDatabase the IValueConverter is not fired.

This is my ListView:
[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKCt9.png)

Comment: Are you implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your ViewModel and invoke the event when `ExistInDatabase` changes?

Comment: Im using Prism so my ViewModel derives from ViewModelBase and my ViewModelBase derives from BindableBase which implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: You still need to call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ExistInDatabase))` when you change it I suppose. That framework won't magically do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

> You still need to call OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ExistInDatabase)) when
>   you change it I suppose. That framework won't magically do it for you.
>   – Biesi Grr

Thanks to your tip Biesi! I did manage to solve the problem.

I've modified the model ExistInDatabase property:

```
public bool ExistInDatabase
        {
            get { return _exitsInDatabase; }
            set
            {
                _exitsInDatabase = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

And added PropertyChangedEventHandler:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

Now whenever user modifies the ListView PropertyChangedEvent is fired and UI is refreshed.

[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoUHo.png)